# Problems translating wire cube

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a program that must translate a wire cube on the screen when the user press the correspondent keys. The main problem occurs when the cube is translated, making several copies of itself, generating some kind of path. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GL/glut.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"
#include "math.h"

#define LARGURA 600
#define ALTURA 500

using namespace std;

const GLfloat INCREMENT = 2.0f;
const GLfloat CUBE_SIZE = 2.0f;

GLfloat X, Y, Z = 0.0f;

void myReshape(int largura, int altura)
{
    largura = LARGURA;
    altura = ALTURA;

    glViewport(0, 0, largura, altura);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glOrtho(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);
    gluPerspective(25.0, largura / altura, 0.1, 500);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void myDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
        gluLookAt(-2.7, 2.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        glTranslatef(X, Y, Z);

        glutWireCube(CUBE_SIZE);
        glutPostRedisplay();

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void myKeyboard(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            X += INCREMENT;
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            X -= INCREMENT;
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_UP:
            Y += INCREMENT;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            Y -= INCREMENT;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_INSERT:
            Z += INCREMENT;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;

        case GLUT_KEY_HOME:
            Z -= INCREMENT;
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    glutInitWindowSize(LARGURA, ALTURA);

    glutInitWindowPosition(400,50);
    glutCreateWindow("Movendo Cubo");

    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutReshapeFunc(myReshape);
    glutSpecialFunc(myKeyboard);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

I've already done everything I could do in order to figure out what's going on... Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the whole display each time `display()` is called, not just the depth buffer:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```